# How to add Facebook access token to web services(json) to access an URL in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have to get the Facebook access token and pass it through URL to get ttsid & then parse the json to get Web services contents.

Comment: Please Check This Link , You will get everything for facebook acess [facebook for ios](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/)

Comment: how to get facebook user id through facebook access token..please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this facebook graph.It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/) and
[Fb ios6](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/).
And you can check there [official tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/). [Fb Graphs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/) might be helpful.

Comment: sir,tnx for ur support..but my problem is to get ttsid from Facebook access token..

Comment: Hi @deepak, You can obtain the secret key from your login id, get the other desired info from the

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials`
See this [Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/)

Comment: tnx sir..let me try this but can i knw wat is client_credentials here..Please

Comment: Sir i am describing u wat to achieve.

Comment: 1-get access token.2-get ttsid 3.from this ttsid call url(web services).please help me..